# Refresh recyclerview when user takes a picture

Tags: java, android, android-recyclerview

I have a fragment that displays the users most recent images on their device. However, this only updates when the user swipes away from the fragment and returns back to it. I'd like to make it so that the pictures update once a picture is taken automatically (no need to swipe away and come back to fragment). How can I go about doing this?

Adapter code:

```js
public class RecentPhotosAdapter extends RecyclerView.Adapter < RecentPhotosAdapter.ViewHolder > {

  // Variables
  private Context mContext;
  private ArrayList < String > mImage;
  private int VIEW_TYPE_DEFAULT = 0;
  private int VIEW_TYPE_IMAGE = 1;

  // Limit the recent photo selection
  int RECENT_PHOTO_LIMIT = 7;

  public RecentPhotosAdapter(Context mContext, ArrayList < String > mImage) {
    this.mContext = mContext;
    this.mImage = mImage;
  }

  @NonNull
  @Override
  public ViewHolder onCreateViewHolder(@NonNull ViewGroup parent, int viewType) {

    if (viewType == VIEW_TYPE_IMAGE) {

      View view = LayoutInflater.from(parent.getContext()).inflate(R.layout.recent_photos_item, parent, false);
      return new ViewHolder(view);
    } else {
      View view = LayoutInflater.from(parent.getContext()).inflate(R.layout.default_select_photos_item, parent, false);
      return new ViewHolder(view);
    }

  }

  @Override
  public void onBindViewHolder(@NonNull ViewHolder holder, int position) {
    if (position < Math.min(mImage.size(), RECENT_PHOTO_LIMIT)) {
      String images = mImage.get(position);

      // Recent Photos
      Glide.with(mContext)
        .load(images)
        .placeholder(R.drawable.background_gallery_placeholder)
        .transform(new CenterCrop(), new RoundedCorners(30))
        .into(holder.recent_photos_iv);

      // Default select photos
      holder.recent_photos_iv.setOnClickListener(new View.OnClickListener() {
        @Override
        public void onClick(View view) {

          // Open horizontalScrollGallery
          Intent intent = new Intent(mContext, HorizontalScrollGalleryActivity.class);
          intent.putExtra("position", String.valueOf(position));
          mContext.startActivity(intent);
        }
      });
    } else {
      holder.default_select_photo_iv.setOnClickListener(new View.OnClickListener() {
        @Override
        public void onClick(View view) {
          // Open SelectImageActivity onClick
          Intent intent = new Intent(mContext, SelectImageActivity.class);
          mContext.startActivity(intent);
        }
      });

      // Open SelectImageActivity when user scrolls to the end of recent images
      Intent intent = new Intent(mContext, SelectImageActivity.class);
      mContext.startActivity(intent);
    }
  }

  @Override
  public int getItemViewType(int position) {
    return (position == Math.min(mImage.size(), RECENT_PHOTO_LIMIT)) ? VIEW_TYPE_DEFAULT : VIEW_TYPE_IMAGE;
  }

  @Override
  public int getItemCount() {
    return Math.min(mImage.size(), RECENT_PHOTO_LIMIT) + 1;
  }

  public class ViewHolder extends RecyclerView.ViewHolder {

    ImageView recent_photos_iv;
    ImageView default_select_photo_iv;

    public ViewHolder(View itemView) {
      super(itemView);
      recent_photos_iv = itemView.findViewById(R.id.recent_photos_iv);
      default_select_photo_iv = itemView.findViewById(R.id.default_select_photo_iv);

    }
  }
}
```

Comment: call `adapter.notifyDataSetChanged();` after the picture is taken

Comment: Could we get a bit more info on this question? 

Are you initiating the photo capture request? If so, you can use onActivityResult, but note there is extra work to get that into a fragment, as onActivityResult is only in the Activity class. Or, are you wanting this to update when a photo is taken from some other source?

Comment: It would like to update it from another source

Answer (score 0):

As per code, you move another screen for capture image. After capturing image you again come back on adapter screen, when you come back on same screen then you need to refresh adapter by calling:

```
mAdapter.notifyDataSetChanged()
```